# Is there a name for the following asymmetry property of a measure on $R$?:

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, symmetry

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. 
I am looking for a name for the following property:
$\int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu \ge 0$ for all skew-symmetric Borel functions $f$ that are non-negative on $[0,\infty)$. This property is equivalent to $\mu(A) \ge \mu(-A)$ for any Borel subset of $[0,\infty)$, i.e. it expresses that the measure gives more weight to any set of positive numbers than to its mirror image.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing that comes to mind is the is to say the measure is [skewed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) so i guess you can say "skewed towards the right" or something like that.